# Export to Excel from Java - InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, export-to-excel, invocationtargetexception

I am stuck at a point while trying to export some data into Excel.

Here is my code

```
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
//////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Added some headers in between to the list               
///////////////////////////////////////////////

HSSFCell[] cell = new HSSFCell[headers.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < headersHSSF.length; i++) {  
  cell[i] = excelRow.createCell(i);    
  cell[i].setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(headers.get(i)));
}
```

This code is throwing InvocationTargetException for line

```
cell[i].setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(headers.get(i)));
```

Can anyone please tell me the reason why is this happening?

**(PS: I am calling the code from Flex UI. This is not called from java code)**

Comment: You'll likely need to provide the stacktrace for that exception.  `InvocationTargetException` merely means that a method that was invoked indirectly (e.g. via reflection) threw a checked exception.  So right now the only information that can be gleaned is "something went wrong." ;-)

Comment: I already have a try-catch surrounding it, it is not showing anything on server console :(

Comment: @pvsm - we *need* the stacktrace, do you have a log? Any chance to log the exception?

Comment: InvocationTargetException uses exception-chaining. Important information is in the stack trace. What do you have in your cach block?

Answer (score 0):

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

Could be, that the exception is thrown while creating a `HSSFRichTextString` class. In this case, I'd look (debug) at the value of `headers.get(i)` first.

There is a good chance, that you actually have a nested `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because the size of the `headersHSSF` array may be bigger than the size of the `headers` list.

Change the loop signature to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
```

and check, if the error is the same, gone or different.